# autodiscover for 2 completly different domains

Tags: exchange, autodiscovery

We got local exchange with domain *karel.com*. But we are part of big company *maruna.com* (we don't have access to this domain,  we just using it). So our primary email for answers is for example jedeme@*maruna.com*. But when I want to connect my email to outlook to our local exchange where are mailboxes, I am still getting the autodiscovery for *maruna.com* but we need to connect to our local exchange can someone help me how to configure autodiscovery for 2 completly different domains?

Comment: Hi, i'm here to confirm the progress of your thread, is there any update? If your problem has been fixed, you could mark the best answer or share your solutions.

Answer (score 1):

How did you add the domain **`maruna.com`** to your email addresses? By **Email Address Policy** or **alternative UPN suffix**?

Do you get any internal/external hostnames related with the domain **`maruna.com`** if you perform an E-mail AutoConfiguration test in Outlook?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Besides, based on the result in the Outlook, make sure the SCP and internal/external URLs/Hostnames of virtual directories aren't pointing to the domain **`maruna.com`**, you could run the following commands in the EMS to see that:

```
Get-OabVirtualDirectory | fl Identity, server, *Auth*, InternalURL, ExternalURL
Get-WebServicesVirtualDirectory | fl Identity, server, *Auth*, InternalURL, ExternalURL 
Get-OutlookAnywhere | fl Identity, server, *Auth*, InternalHostName, ExternalHostName 
Get-OwaVirtualDirectory | fl Identity, server, *Auth*, InternalURL, ExternalURL 
Get-ClientAccessService | fl Identity, Name, AutodiscoverServiceInternalUri 
Get-EcpVirtualDirectory| fl Identity, server, *Auth*, InternalURL, ExternalURL 
Get-ActiveSyncVirtualDirectory | fl Identity, server, *Auth*, InternalURL, ExternalURL
Get-MapiVirtualDirectory | fl Identity, server, *Auth*, InternalURL, ExternalURL 
Get-PowerShellVirtualDirectory | fl Identity, server, *Auth*, InternalURL, ExternalURL
```